# How to access flume event header attributes?

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have added few event header attributes in `Flume` but I am not sure how to access it in the flumeagent config file

Ex: I have added fileHeader using

`flumeagent.sinks.sinkname.hdfs.fileHeader = true`

The goal is to be able to add event header attributes in the path, 
Ex: `flumeagent.sinks.sinkname.hdfs.path = /user/name/flumedir/%y-%m-%d/event-attribute`

Answer (score 1):

Found out you can add filename or absolute file path using the following

`flumeagent.sources.src1.fileHeader = true
flumeagent.sources.src1.fileHeaderKey = file`

`flumeagent.sources.src1.basenameHeader = true
flumeagent.sources.src1.basenameHeaderKey = basename`

Note: the above are added in sources but it is used in sinks

`flumeagent.sinks.sinkname.hdfs.path = /user/name/flumedir/%y-%m-%d/%{file}`
or
`flumeagent.sinks.sinkname.hdfs.path = /user/name/flumedir/%y-%m-%d/%{basename}`